# Norwegian user interface in libreoffice

Tags: xubuntu, libreoffice, snap, spell-checking

For one year I have used LibreOffice with an English user interface and no working Norwegian spell checking in ubuntu 20.04.  The spell checking works when I set the language to English.

To day I decided to look into this, and find that my LibreOffice 7.1.2.2 is a snap install and there is only a version 6 in the apt.

Has anyone managed to get a Norwegian interface and get Norwegian spell checking working with a snap install?  If so please help or I may have to reinstall with a ppa

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with  flatpak and Greek spell-checking. I ended up installing the dictionary as an add-on.
There is also a Norwegian dictionary as an add-on.

https://extensions.libreoffice.org/en/extensions/show/norsk-stavekontroll-bokmal-og-nynorsk

Of course this leaves you with an english interface.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I uninstalled the snap and downgraded to the apt-version.  Will look into this later